# Using built in Multiprocessing module python in a cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, multiprocessing

I need to compute a massive data in one of the endpoint in my fastapi backend application. I tried using multiprocess locally and it was fast. I have a k8s cluster in AWS Server, Do you think its advisable to use pythons inbuilt multiprocessing module in a cluster. Will it be an issue when we want to scale up.

I found about fiber multiprocessing by Uber. But looks like they stopped updating it and not sure if it still works.

I implemented multiprocess in the AWS k8s cluster and it didnt have any issues. Just wanted to know how it will react when it scales up in the longer run.

Comment: The multiprocessing module can spread load over the CPUs on one host. To distribute the load over multiple hosts you will need multiple service instances and a framework that coordinates them.

Comment: Will there be any issues when If use one host when scaling up?. I need to compute like 15,000 documents in my database. with multiprocessing it takes like 8 secs on my local. I use 2 processes and divide the documents into chunks and process. There was no any issue when I deployed this code. it took like 12 seconds in the cluster. I am worried there will be issues when I scale up later. What do you recommend using for multiple hosts some frameworks?

Comment: For a load of 8 to 12 seconds I wouldn't worry about it at all. Your task doesn't sound like it is time critical. I would run it with low priority (increased niceness in Linux terms) in one pod.

Comment: Thsnks Klaus for the clarification